Oauth process in Outlook App, getting parameter of the uri scheme
I have a button in my Outlook custom add-in (taskpane), which redirects the user to a custom Laravel project for login. Once the user successfully logs in to the Laravel project, it should redirect back to or open the Outlook desktop app.
I'm using a uri scheme like the example below to open Outlook and include the authorization code as a parameter:
Example: ms-outlook://folders/inbox?code=1234
However, I want to get the code parameter into my taskpane.js file within the Outlook custom add-in I created
I also noticed that when the Outlook desktop app opens, it displays a message saying,
"Unknown host in the URL."

